# Admin login not working on production

Tags: admin, login

My admin username is not working on production. It works locally. I can change the password and add a new admin user, which works fine locally. Has anyone run into this before? Prod is on a Mediatemple server using php 7.4.21 and the Craft version is 3.5.5

Comment: Can you log into the admin on production using a different browser (or incognito window) than the you use for local dev?

Answer (score 1):

Check your ["cpTrigger"](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#cptrigger) in the `craftcmsfolder/config/general.php`

Comment: That's set correctly, the problem is I can login with the admin username on local but prod is showing incorrect username or password. I can verify the DB is correct in both.

Comment: If you are 100% sure that the users are the same (username and password hash in the tables locally and on the prod are the same), then, as I understand it, this is hosting, and, perhaps, just some PHP functions are turned off?
Maybe the versions of PHP, extensions, functions differ locally and on the production?
Can you basically log in to production as any user?

Comment: If you can’t login at all, then check if there are `hash_equals` and `password_verify` functions